# Hide webpage URL until successful login

Tags: javascript, html, url, servlets

I have a public webpage with links to all kinds of apps for government institutions. I was asked to hide those links, that users can't see where they are redirected. All apps have login forms, but still they don't like that everyone can see those links. 
Well, I wrote a servlet that redirects to those urls, so they are out of the webpages source code. Then I printed new page with iframe from servlet, URL in adressbar is also gone, but still you can see url in souce of page. Browser won't allow to disable right click anymore so I'm kinda stuck here. 
Only thing that come to my mind is to make a login form that would pass username & password to that actual login form and return the page only on successful login. But I'm not sure how it can be done. Is it even possible?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible CSRF and XSS vunerability waiting to happen here

Comment: I don't think complete hiding is possible due to security problems.

Comment: Ever considered using a token of some kind that translates to an url? (E.g. translate.php will return an url if you pass it a token when you are logged in. The token is then invalidated. If you pass translate.php a token without being logged in it will return an error of some kind.)

Answer (score 4):

> I was asked to hide those links, that users can't see where they are redirected.

This is impossible. The browser has to know where to request the data from in order to get the data.

> All apps have login forms, but still they don't like that everyone can see those links.

That's like putting a lock on a house and being unhappy that people can still know the address. You need to secure the system, not try to hide it.

Comment: **"The browser has to know where to request the data from in order to get the data."** But can't it be done from server? User sends login information and app name to server, then server finds url for the app name and tries to log in the app. On success it redirect to url with login details, so user is logged in?

Comment: @Belamors — When you redirect, the server responds to the browser's request with a message saying "What you want is actually at this other URL". Then the browser makes a new request to the other URL. So no, that won't hide anything.

Comment: But I need to hide that URL just until user credentials are verified. When he's logged in and app opens, then of course URL can be seen, but I want to hide apps URL for users that are not logged in yet. Isn't that possible at all? Networking guys said that it can be somehow done by reverse proxy, but I don't fully understand how.